Azure DevOps Pipeline Stuck and Self-Hosted Agent Offline Issue
When running a pipeline on Azure DevOps, my self-hosted agent, which is running on an EC2 instance, sometimes gets stuck, and the agent goes offline. After this happens, I'm unable to SSH into my EC2 instance. Could this be due to an AWS service outage or something else?
Here is my pipeline configuration:
# Dependabot
# Maven
# Build your Java project and run tests with Apache Maven.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

schedules:
  - cron: "0 12 * * 0"
    displayName: Weekly Dependency Updates
    branches:
      include:
      - main
    always: true
    
trigger: 
- master

pool:
  name: TestAgent
  demands:
   - Agent.Name -equals NewAgent
stages:
  - stage: CheckDependencies
    displayName: 'Check Dependencies'
    jobs:
      - job: Dependabot
        displayName: 'Run Dependabot'
        variables:
        - name: DIRECTORY_PATH
          value: /
        - name: PACKAGE_MANAGER
          value: bundler
        - name: PROJECT_PATH
          value: sugamarora23/_git/DriveEasy
          # Optional : User to assign to the created pull request
          # Name : Assignee
          # value : any
        steps:
          - task: dependabot@1
            displayName: 'Run Dependabot'
            inputs:
              failOnException: false
          - script: git clone https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-script.git
            displayName: Clone Dependabot config repo
          
          - script: |
              cd dependabot-script
              docker build -t "dependabot/dependabot-script" -f Dockerfile . 
            displayName: Build Dependabot Image
          
          - script: |
              docker run --rm -e AZURE_ACCESS_TOKEN='$(PAT)' \
                              -e GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN='$(GHPAT)' \
                              -e PACKAGE_MANAGER='$(PACKAGE_MANAGER)' \
                              -e PROJECT_PATH='$(PROJECT_PATH)' \
                              -e DIRECTORY_PATH='$(DIRECTORY_PATH)' \
                              dependabot/dependabot-script
            displayName: Dependabot

Do you think the issue could be related to this configuration, or is it more likely an AWS service outage?
What I tried:
I set up a pipeline on Azure DevOps using a self-hosted agent running on an EC2 instance. The pipeline includes a schedule for weekly dependency updates using Dependabot, which is triggered on the master branch. The pipeline is configured to run on a specific agent pool (TestAgent) and demands a specific agent name (NewAgent). The pipeline stages include checking dependencies and running Dependabot to update dependencies.
What I expected to happen:
I expected the pipeline to run successfully on my self-hosted agent, updating dependencies as scheduled and completing the pipeline stages without any issues.
What actually resulted:
Sometimes, during the pipeline execution, the self-hosted agent running on the EC2 instance gets stuck, and the agent goes offline. After this happens, I'm unable to SSH into my EC2 instance. This behavior is intermittent and does not happen consistently, leading to uncertainty about the cause of the issue.
Do you have any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Updates :
Changing project manager to maven as my application is java based and using t2a.medium instance rather than t2.micro instance type resolve the following conflict
